# Theoretical limits of CCK (Field API) unlimited Multi Value Field - 170 000 values

Tags: entities, performance

I plan to have a large multi value field, in my case a node reference field, around 170 000 values.

I guess on node view I can hide the field, and just put in a Views block so the node can be viewed. Editing the node manually will be impossible, as the multi value fields have no paging and Drupal would just load the entire 170 000 values onto the screen. Any tips on solving this?

What I plan on having this is a content type "list" and a content type "item". In the items I will load an dictionary word lists, and in the "list" content type I will group them in different lists. I could use taxonomy as well, but nodes have a better permission control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No chance, hiding doesn't help, drupal will still load all values even if the field is hidden.

You could add the reference field on the item type and then load them through a view.

Or use the relation project, but it's ui might break too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a node reference field, you can use the autocomplete widget. That way Drupal won't load all the values into the form. That is the suggested way if you have more than 20-100 values in regard to usability.

In terms of performance, the number of values won't matter since drupal will do a simple matching against available nodes and check if the selected value is valid. Autocomplete will be harder to use with 170k values, but performance should be more or less the same. (The query run don't depend on what's in the database)

Comment: He is talking about having 170k field values. Autocomplete doesn't help as it still displays a Textfield per value